# Integral $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

It is known that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

However, it is not so clear how fast $\int_0^{t} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} dx$
converges to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ as $t$ goes to infinity. Also, the following definite integral with trigonometric function often appears in various scientific areas, for example, the analysis on quantum information.

$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} dx.$$

Therefore, I am seeking analytical solution of the above definite integral.

Comment: What have you attempted already?

Comment: Naively I might suggest Lobachevsky’s integral formula.

Comment: $\operatorname{Si}(2\pi)$ is the best "closed form" you'll find for this.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \frac{\sin^2 (x)}{x^2} dx=-\frac 12\int \frac { \cos(2x)-1}{x^2} dx$$Integrate by parts

$$\int \frac { \cos(2x)-1}{x^2} dx=-\frac{ \cos(2x)-1}{x}-2\int\frac {\sin(2x)}{x} dx$$
$$\int\frac {\sin(2x)}{x} dx=\int\frac {\sin(2x)}{2x} d(2x)=\text{Si}(2 x)$$
As a total
$$\int \frac{\sin^2 (x)}{x^2} dx=\text{Si}(2 x)+\frac{ \cos(2x)-1}{2x}+C$$
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin^2 (x)}{x^2} dx=\text{Si}(2 \pi)$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2( x)}{x^2} dx=\frac \pi 2$$

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is Si(2$\pi$). I could find the definition of Si(x) in the following;https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral